# How can I install CodeIgniter core (system) files using Composer?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

How can I install just the codeigniter core (system) code using Composer?

Comment: The package [`codeigniter/framework`](https://packagist.org/packages/codeigniter/framework) is available since 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be what you are after, but the obvious answer is to create a `composer.json` file and require "ellislab/codeigniter" - this will install whatever is offered, as a complete package.

I have no experience with CodeIgniter, but I think this will install more than you need. I have not seen and way to just install the `system` directory. This would only be possible if CodeIgniter would offer this as a separate package - and they don't.

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled over the project that does just that - [codeigniter-composer](https://github.com/rogeriopradoj/codeigniter-composer). Never used it though, simply was searching for a similar thing and this popped out.